# Retrofit2 & Fabric, Crashlytics cannot be used

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2, android-studio-2.1, crashlytics-android

I am using Retrofit 2.0.2 and Fabric 1.21.6 in app.I am not able to request any api using retrofit as it gives the following error.

I followed the solution stated in git : https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/issues/28 , https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1152

```
Could not find class 'retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder', referenced from method com.wolfmatrix.navz.restApi.service.RestClient.getClient
    05-26 18:20:20.266 24072-24072/com.wolfmatrix.navz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.wolfmatrix.navz, PID: 24072
                                                                         java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder
```